# Unload and beforeunload events when removing iframe from the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, iframe

I have 2 questions. First I noticed that when I remove an iframe from the DOM, the on unload event is triggered automatically. I tested it with jQuery remove() and detach() methods. Is it a jQuery feature, browser specific or can I always assume that when an iframe is removed from the dom, its onunload event is triggered automatically?

My second question is about beforeunload event, this event is not triggered when iframe is removed. This could lead to data loss, as the navigation blocking modal won't be shown, the iframe is removed in an instant. As a workaround, I change the location to about:blank before removing it. But I'm wondering if there's a better way. Can I trigger the on beforeunload event, without changing the location?

Comment: I know this is old, but.. if you have control of both the iframe content and the parent content, you can use the `postMessage` api to communicate with the frame in any way you need. (Furthermore, if the frame is same-origin, you can even access all the js content of the inner `window` within it via `contentWindow`).
If you can't control the iframe content, I can't think of a better solution than what you have.